# How to pass function from Context to App.js in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

When I run the app, the error message shows that `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useContext.state')`

Here is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Context as ActivitiesContext, Provider } from "./context/ActivitiesContext";

const App = () => {

  const { state, getActivity } = useContext(ActivitiesContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    getActivity()
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open App.js to start working on your file</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default App
```

Here is my ActivitiesContext.js:

```
import createDataContext from "./CreateDataContext";

const getActivity = () => {
  return console.log("hi");
};

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
  {
    getActivity,
  }
);
```

Here is my CreateDataContext.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

export default (reducer, action, defaultValue) => {
    const Context = React.createContext();

    const Provider = ({ children }) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);

        const boundActions = {};

        for (let key in action) {
            boundActions[key] = action[key](dispatch);
        }

        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    };

    return { Context: Context, Provider: Provider };
};
```

I am expecting that the `console.log("hi")` from the function `getActivity` be passed to the App.js and console log "hi".

There also is the Provider, what is its purpose and how do I use it? I think that's what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create `context`
2. Use `Provider` to pass a value by wrapping an component to provide access for components deeper in the tree
3. Use `useContext` to access the value from any of the components

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext(); // 1.

const App = () => {
  // 2.
  return <ThemeContext.Provider value={{color: 'black', getColor: () => 'red'}}> 
      <MyComponet />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
}

const MyComponet = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <MyButton />
    </View>
  );
}

const MyButton = () => {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext) // 3.
 
  return <Button title="Button" color={theme.getColor()}/>;
}
```